# Help figure out where this phantom rust is coming from

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

I have an object with two non intersecting UV Maps.  One UV Map (round.red.light.decal) is to place a red light decal (round.red.light.png).  The other UV Map (rust.map) was used to draw an image mask (cabin.rust.mask.png).

I have my nodes as such...

[image]

But I have some phantom rust that I did not draw in my mask.  The face the red light is on isn't even in the rust UV map.

[image]

Thanks for any insight.  Here is my blend file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ZnFrE6fxi_ZDNIanAyQ001RlE

Comment: I can't open the file now ,but try selecting everything in edit mode while viewing the rust uvmap  probably the face mesh is misplaced

Comment: I did as you suggested and everything looked as it should be.  I reset the red light uv map because I removed it by accident.  That seemed to fix the problem.  I don't know what the problem was or why it was fixed.  But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Wild guess: flipped normal?

Answer (score 0):

When vertices touch on UV map, you might get stray color effects like that.
You want a little bit of space between each UV "island"

Edit mode > Mesh > UV Unwrap > Smart UV Project
Island Margin > something small, like 0.05

[image: Island Margin]

Comment: This will create new UV map which can be undesired if the OP already unwrapped their mesh and would like to work with existing map

Comment: Yeah, that's true.  It will create a new UV map.  I should have pointed that out.  I was thinking that deanresin already solved his issue, so wasn't actually gonna do this right away, and it was just info to keep in mind for next time.